# Computer components keep failing! Could it be my PSU?

Tags: hard-drive, graphics-card, ssd, power-supply

Less than a year ago, a friend and I built my computer, and ever since I've had outrageous hardware problems.
First the Windows 8 installation my 1 TB HDD was continuously corrupted, forcing me to reinstall Windows every other month or so. Eventually it got so bad that I got a 240 GB PNY SSD to run Windows. (The HDD could still be used as storage, it just wasn't stable enough for an OS.)

Everything was fine for a month or so until my graphics card started having connection issues with my motherboard. After a few weeks of random crashes (horizontal lines, screen blackouts, forced reboots, the whole deal) it stopped working completely, and I replaced that old AMD Radeon HD 6570 with a GeForce 750-Ti.

A few days ago while on a Skype call, my screen froze and I had to force-reboot. After that my computer wouldn't recognize nor boot from my SSD. I tried switching cables, unplugging my HDD, even swapping computers, but my SSD was dead.

So here I am, and I'm afraid to buy new components if they will just keep failing. My friend who shares many of the same parts (all but the SSD, actually) has had no troubles for over a year. Is the trouble with my motherboard? Power supply? Please help!

Current Specs:

Windows 8.1 64-bit

MSI MS-7798 Motherboard

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.2GHz

8GB RAM (2x4GB Corsair)

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Edit: PSU = CX600

Comment: Is the PSU from a reputable brand or the cheapest one you could find?

Comment: Add the PSU details please.

Comment: @Andrew I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be either, but it does sounds like either the motherboard or PSU.

A PSU is usually far less expensive, I recommend replacing it for a month (or until an issue) as a test.  Often you can get one with the minimum wattage you need second-hand from a friend or reputable computer parts shop for cheap or free.

Until you get hard data from that test, anything else posted here is just speculation.

Comment: Would it be possible to test the PSU, perhaps measuring the voltage for any irregularities?